# Reverse Geocoding - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'

Tags: here-api

I have a Freemium account and have 2 REST API keys generated. I get the following error when I use either one of the keys -

HTTPConnectionPool(host='batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /6.2/jobs? prox=%5B24.47%2C+24.78%2C+48.2%2C+-33.87%2C+50.85%2C+26.21%2C+-22.92%2C+-22.34%2C+50.91%2C+47.41%2C+-33.39%2C+39.92%2C+39.79%5D%2C%5B54.34%2C+55.6%2C+16.36%2C+151.21%2C+4.36%2C+50.57%2C+-43.24%2C+-49.05%2C+-114.07%2C+8.54%2C+-70.52%2C+116.17%2C+116.51%5D&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=9&apiKey=-l7nmoOoBBAH3fHWUg2QYL6FB3qLcEvb88MRFTUuE5A (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

I am following [https://developer.here.com/blog/reverse-geocoding-a-location-using-python]
I also followed the docs to build my GET request [https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/geocoder/reverse-geocode] I have no idea what is going on. I have been stuck the past week trying to figure this out. It is beyond me. I am new to programming, python, stackoverflow ....everything! Tech Support, could you please advice? Thanks.

I am using Python. The goal is to reverse geocode 25,000 points from a CSV file and write to the CSV file. My code for reverse geocoding -

```
# Request URL
request_url = "https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json"

# API key
#api_key1 = 'MY API KEY 1'
api_key2 = 'MY API KEY 2'

# setting the parameters to be sent along with the request_url in the GET request
parametres = {
                'prox': '{},{}'.format(latitude_list,longitude_list),
                'mode': 'retrieveAddresses',
                'maxresults': 1,
                'gen': 9,
                'apiKey': api_key2                 
             }

# send a GET request
response = requests.get (url = request_url, params = parametres)
print(response.status_code)

# check if the request was successful and get the JSON response data
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Request successful.')
    data = response.json()
    print(data)
else:
    print('Request failed.')
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct working code-

```
import random
import time
import pandas as pd
import requests


latitude = 12.9716
longitude = 77.5946
file_name = 'data.csv'


def generate_random_data(lat, lon, num_rows, file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'a') as output:
        output.write('timestamp,latitude,longitude\n')
        for _ in range(num_rows):
            time_stamp = time.time()
            generated_lat = random.random()/100
            generated_lon = random.random()/100
            output.write("{},{},{}\n".format(
                time_stamp, lat+generated_lat, lon+generated_lon))


generate_random_data(latitude, longitude, 10, file_name)

# To read 6th row data
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", skiprows=5, nrows=1)

# To print the values
print(data)

# To convert values into list
list_value = data.values.tolist()

# Latitude and Longitude
latitude = list_value[0][1]
longitude = list_value[0][2]

print(latitude, longitude)

request_url = "https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json"

# API key

api_key = 'your rest api key'

# setting the parameters to be sent along with the request_url in the GET request
parametres = {
    'prox': '{},{}'.format(latitude, longitude),
    'mode': 'retrieveAddresses',
    'maxresults': 1,
    'gen': 9,
    'apiKey': api_key
}

# send a GET request
response = requests.get(url=request_url, params=parametres)
print(response.status_code)

# check if the request was successful and get the JSON response data
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Request successful.')
    data = response.json()
    print(data)
else:
    print('Request failed.')
```

and it gives the below response-

> > Request successful. {'Response': {'MetaInfo': {'Timestamp': '2020-06-17T11:50:24.706+0000'}, 'View': [{'_type':
> > 'SearchResultsViewType', 'ViewId': 0, 'Result': [{'Relevance': 1.0,
> > 'Distance': -429.0, 'Direction': 16.2, 'MatchLevel': 'district',
> > 'MatchQuality': {'Country': 1.0, 'State': 1.0, 'County': 1.0, 'City':
> > 1.0, 'District': 1.0, 'PostalCode': 1.0}, 'Location': {'LocationId': 'NT_ncA49aCPF2GKSWJE4kP26C', 'LocationType': 'area',
> > 'DisplayPosition': {'Latitude': 12.98721, 'Longitude': 77.60402},
> > 'MapView': {'TopLeft': {'Latitude': 12.99579, 'Longitude': 77.58896},
> > 'BottomRight': {'Latitude': 12.97306, 'Longitude': 77.61544}},
> > 'Address': {'Label': 'Shivajinagar, Bengaluru, KA, India', 'Country':
> > 'IND', 'State': 'KA', 'County': 'Bengaluru', 'City': 'Bengaluru',
> > 'District': 'Shivajinagar', 'PostalCode': '560051', 'AdditionalData':
> > [{'value': 'India', 'key': 'CountryName'}, {'value': 'Karnataka',
> > 'key': 'StateName'}, {'value': 'Bengaluru', 'key': 'CountyName'}]},
> > 'MapReference': {'ReferenceId': '846137287', 'MapId': 'RRAM20115',
> > 'MapVersion': 'Q1/2020', 'MapReleaseDate': '2020-06-08',
> > 'SideOfStreet': 'neither', 'CountryId': '22806254', 'StateId':
> > '22798588', 'CountyId': '22799633', 'CityId': '22803543',
> > 'DistrictId': '28032363'}}}]}]}}